# .net model binding difference POST vs GET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have an .net MVC application. Can't figure out what is the difference binding model on http `GET` and `POST` methods.

e.g.
`CULTURE: lt-LT`. Decimal separator '`,`'.

I pass decimal as invariant culture via `ajax` to `GET` - it binds:

> 16.52 --> GET --> 16.52

I pass decimal as invariant culture via `ajax` to `POST` - it does not bind.

> 16.52 --> POST --> 0 (default)
>
> 16,52 --> POST --> 16.52

```
$.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
         cache: false,
         data:
         {
             Separator: "19.99"
         }
 });
```

Controller action:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Action(UpdateModel model)
  {
     //model.Separator
  }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Show what you actually send and how.

Comment: I think it's clear enougth, isn' it?
16,52 ajax[GET] --> controller action[GET](UpdateModel model)  BINDS model's value, but [POST] requires not invariant, but specified culture. Where's the difference?

Comment: What do you mean by the get-part? You can't send data to the server with HTTP GET (other than querystring-parameter). So is that part relevant to the question at all?

Comment: how do you set the culture that Action expects?

Comment: would help if you post your javascript code for the GET

Comment: 0.Yes Esko, it will querystring parameters.
1. Culture set in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute;
2. [GET]. Just remove HttpPost attribute from Action, and method property from ajax.

Comment: the only difference might exactly be what @Esko suggested: on GET the `UpdateModel` is built from query paramters, on POST from request json body. Maybe they have different serializers